# Python breaks http response status code after trying to alter returned response with a new array or map

Tags: python, flutter, http

I tried to alter a response body in lambda before returning to my front end (Flutter). However I got status code 500 internal server error even though in my cloudwatch log, it shows printing of the newly created response ok.

my lambda code where i got `sample_json_response` and try to rebuild the response with a new list (also tried with dict but both returned same result

```
            # print(sample_json_response)
            ingredient_response = json.dumps(inference_response['body']['ingredients']['items'])
            print('ingredient response: ')
            print(ingredient_response)
            
            # add _id details to return unique id for identifying documentdb result
            unique_id = request_id + "-" + upload_timestamp
            result = []
            result.append("unique_id": unique_id)
            result.append("ingredient_response": ingredient_response)
            print('updated result: ')
            print(result)
```

After that i return the response with status code 200 and body

```
       return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': result
                }
```

I checked in my log the array or map printed ok, no error in my lambda as well. This image shows the new array i built, just prepending with additional details
[image]

however i got error 500 internal server error in my flutter end. when i print from response.statusCode it shows 500. If i change back to my initial sample response, it works ok.

What's the reason causing the status code overwritten when i am returning the same format but just rebuilding to a new array and trying to add details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause. It is because API Gateway does not handle the newly built response and stringify it automatically. As a result, the response sent back via API Gateway was deemed as malformed. Need to:
`json.dumps(result)` and it is all good now.